# why getting inside PHPdebugger?

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

Problem started from here.
page1.php code snippet:

```
<a href=page2.php?subid=1>xyz</a>
```

Nothing related gets logged in php error log. Tried try.. catch block and this seems page1.php works perfectly but gets in trouble while redirecting to page2.php. the javaBridge connection breaks?

```
PHP notice: Undefined index: start_debug, debug_host, debug_port in PHPdebugger.php
PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to :0
```

Moreover, PHPdebugger.php is an automatically generated file for JavaBridge (JavaBridge/java/PHPdebugger.php) so there can't be any issue in the file.

Comment: try wrapping the href in quotes `<a href="page2.php?subid=1">xyz</a>`

Comment: already tried that.. but still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Looks there's an issue with latest version of the bridge (7.0.1) which enables the PHPDebugger by default. See the mailing list archive: https://sourceforge.net/p/php-java-bridge/mailman/message/35776970/.

Check for newer version or downgrade to 6.2.1.

Alternatively a forked version exists (https://github.com/belgattitude/php-java-bridge/releases) with the PHPDebugger disabled by default. A basic installation can be found [here](http://docs.soluble.io/soluble-japha/install_server/), but will drop support of the `Java.inc` in favour of the [soluble-japha](https://github.com/belgattitude/soluble-japha) client in coming releases (major version only).